Making code updates to my React App hosted on AWS EC2 and an Nginx server
What is the easiest way to update code on my nginx server when I make changes?
I have basically followed along with this tutorial and have a React website up and running. Do I make updates locally on VS Code and push them to GitHub? Then I'm not sure of the steps to update it on the server.
Also, I am receiving "dependabot" alerts on GitHub to update some package.json dependencies that will need to reflect on the Nginx server after installing the new dependencies using npm i.
I see Netlify automatically updates code changes to React apps, but I suppose I do it manually each time code changes are made somehow.
https://www.netlify.com/with/react/
I've tried deleting an EC2 instance and just starting over with a new instance and start over (at the appropriate step) with the tutorial here:
https://medium.com/@rizkiprass/step-by-step-guide-deploying-a-react-app-on-aws-ec2-b2965af05aa4
